# Use python request to login website

Tags: python, unicode, python-requests

Here is the code I have, it's working on another site but not on this one:

```
import requests
import sys

url = 'url'
payload = {'email': '123@123.com', 'password': '123'}

# Post the info and make request
requests.post(url, data=payload)
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(url, data=payload)

    r = s.get(url)
    test_data = r.text

    for row in test_data:
        sys.stdout.write(row)
```

[image: Here is the screenshot of inspector]
Here is the screenshot of inspector

And I cannot login. It seems that this will just get me to back to the login page. I tried pass in the oid and locale, and it still doesn't work.

The other problem I have is I can't print the result and get error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried the decode and encode method I found here, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Tried changing `r.text` for `r.content`. What does that show? `r.text` is a unicode object, and `r.content` is a string, so it could be that it's trying to convert to a string from unicode, screwing up encoding. But unicode errors always confuse me...

Comment: @Zizouz212 the print r.content works without any errors.    But I still can't login.

Comment: Do you get a `UnicodeEncodeError` there?

Comment: @Zizouz212 No, print r.content doesn't give me error message anymore. It runs for 20 sec and prints out the login page.

Comment: Hmm... It feels like there is something up with your request. Not sure though.

Comment: There are some hidden input fields on the form - `oid` and `locale`. They might make a difference. Also you might want to try setting a User-Agent from a real browser - some sites check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this works, when I change http to https ... (what a nice way to spend the evening, thank you guys)

```
import requests
import sys

url = 'https://www.snapengage.com/signin'
payload = {'email': '123@123.com', 'password': '123'}


# Post the info and make request
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post(url, data=payload)

    r = s.get('https://www.snapengage.com/account/accountInfo')
    test_data = r.text

    for row in test_data:
        sys.stdout.write(row)
```

Comment: letting users post sign-in information over http would be very unsecured. Do not hesitate to let us know what you are trying to do through this Python sign-in, we might be able to point you to a more developer friendly solution.